# When trying set corsheaders in settings.py file

Tags: django, django-cors-headers

(corsheaders.E014) Origin 'http://localhost:4200/' in CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST should not have path .Im getting this error.

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:4200/',
)

Origin 'http://localhost:4200/' in CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST should not have path .Im getting this error.

Answer (score 69):

Remove the slash (`/`) from the end of the line (after the number 4200), leaving it as:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ( 'http://localhost:4200', )
```

That should make it work.

Comment: Why doesn't Django like trailing slashes? This seems to be a common issue